# How to import numbered files in R

Tags: r, import

I have multiple files named `xdata.ascii` and `x` is a number. How can I import all the files with names from `1data.ascii` to, for example, `100data.ascii`. I have other `.ascii` files that have a different name and do not want to import them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `list.files` to get all the files that have the pattern

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\d+data\\.ascii", full.names = TRUE)
```

Then read the files by looping over with `lapply` into a `list`

```
lst <- lapply(files, read.csv)
```

Comment: When I use `is.data.frame(lst)`, it returns `FALSE`. How can I get the data as data frame?

Comment: @MOON It is a `list` of `data.frame` and not a single `data.frame`.  Suppose you wanted to bind all the data.frame, use `do.call(rbind, lst)` assuming that the columns are the same in all the datasets or `library(data.table); rbindlist(lst)`

Comment: Could you please explain the code a little bit. I understand that `\d` is decimal. I do not understand "\\" in the beginning or end of "\\d+data\\".

Comment: @MOON Sure.  The `\\d+`  which means numbers `+` implies one or more followed by `data`, followed by a `dot` which is a metacharacter so we have to escape it with `\\` to get the literal meaning of `.` otherwise it is evaluated as any character followed by `ascii`